# OfType filter throwing {document} is not supported error

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to filter a collection based on object types as follows:

```
query &= Builders<JournalEntry>.Filter.OfTypes (EntryTypes);
```

Where JournalEntry is an abstract class and EntryTypes is an enumerable of System.Type.

Executing this query returns the following error:

> {document} is not supported.
>      at `MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.GetFieldExpression(Expression expression)`

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

I'm using v2.2.4 of the driver.